# Count the max sequence length

Tags: mysql

I have a table with the following data

```
(1995, 'a'),
(1996, 'a'),
(1997, 'a'),
(1998, 'a'),
(2000, 'a'),

(1995, 'b'),
(1997, 'b'),
(1998, 'b'),

(1995, 'c'),
(1999, 'c'),
(2000, 'c'),

(1999, 'd'),

(1999, 'e'),

(1999, 'f');
```

I need to count the max sequence length for each alphabet, e.g. since 'a' is present in 1995,1996,1997,1998 continuously the max sequence length for 'a' is 4. The expected output is:

```
a-4
b-2
c-2
d-1
e-1
f-1
```

Comment: You need to define "continuously" (at least, with respect of which field should order being looked up) as in SQL there's no such thing as "continuously" by nature - records are not ordered by themselves, they may be ordered only in some select query result set - thus, it must be done by some field

Comment: @AlmaDo is uncharacterisitcally incorrect in this instance. Everything that needs to be defined is defined.

Comment: @AlmaDo "continuously" is based on "year" field as in the example above

Comment: What is defined? I can't see fields definitions, as well as the expectation of - what will happen if, let's say, it will be `1991-a, 1992-a, 1993-b, 1994-a`

Comment: @AlmaDo in your case max sequence length for 'a' will be 2 and 'b' will be 1.

Comment: But what about last 'a' entry? just discarded?

Comment: This is a "simple sequence starts and ends problem"

Comment: @AlmaDo not discarded, we are counting the max continuous sequence, in your example 'a' has two continuous sequences 1991,1992 and 1994 since the second sequence has length 1 we take the 1st sequence.

Comment: @Strawberry can you please help by giving more details

Comment: @Strawberry I tried on my server with around 30K records and mysql just froze, is it possible to alter the query so that it works with large dataset.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the following:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_table;

CREATE TABLE my_table (year INT NOT NULL,string CHAR(1) NOT NULL,PRIMARY KEY(year,string));

INSERT INTO my_table VALUES
    (1995, 'a'),
    (1996, 'a'),
    (1997, 'a'),
    (1998, 'a'),
    (2000, 'a'),

    (1995, 'b'),
    (1997, 'b'),
    (1998, 'b'),

    (1995, 'c'),
    (1999, 'c'),
    (2000, 'c'),

    (1999, 'd'),

    (1999, 'e'),

    (1999, 'f');

SELECT string
     , MAX(diff) FROM
     ( SELECT a.string
            , a.year start
            , MIN(c.year) end 
            , MIN(c.year) - a.year+1 diff
         FROM my_table a
         LEFT 
         JOIN my_table b
           ON b.string = a.string
          AND b.year + 1 = a.year
         LEFT 
         JOIN my_table c
           ON c.string = a.string
          AND c.year >= a.year
         LEFT 
         JOIN my_table d
           ON d.string = a.string
          AND d.year - 1 = c.year
        WHERE b.string IS NULL 
          AND c.string IS NOT NULL
          AND d.string IS NULL
        GROUP 
           BY a.string,a.year
     ) a 
 GROUP 
    BY string; 

+--------+-----------+
| string | MAX(diff) |
+--------+-----------+
| a      |         4 |
| b      |         2 |
| c      |         2 |
| d      |         1 |
| e      |         1 |
| f      |         1 |
+--------+-----------+
```

Edit: I have an aesthetic aversion to variables, but in truth, where performance is concerned, they're much more efficient...

```
SELECT string
     , MAX(i) 
  FROM
     (
       SELECT year
            , string
            , IF(year=@prev_year+1,IF(string=@prev_string,@i:=@i+1,@i:=1),@i:=1)i
            , @prev_year := year
            , @prev_string := string 
         FROM my_table
            , ( SELECT @prev_year=0,@prev_string:='',@i:=1 ) vars 
        ORDER 
           BY string
            , year
     ) x
 GROUP 
    BY string;
+--------+--------+
| string | MAX(i) |
+--------+--------+
| a      |      4 |
| b      |      2 |
| c      |      2 |
| d      |      1 |
| e      |      1 |
| f      |      1 |
+--------+--------+
```

Comment: I tried on my server with around 30K records and mysql just froze, is it possible to alter the query so that it works with large dataset.

Comment: A solution using variables would likely perform better. See edit.

Comment: Thanks but the updated query is giving incorrect result on my server for 5.5.40-MariaDB MariaDB though working fine on sqlfiddle. Really strange.

Comment: There were some typos in my previous answer. That might be it.

Answer (score 0):

I think below code would help you .,

```
SELECT string, COUNT(string) AS MAX
FROM my_table
GROUP BY string
HAVING COUNT(string)>=1;
```